# How to install AR5523 chipset wifi in Ubuntu 12.04?

Tags: 12.04, wireless, usb, usb-drive, atheros

My usb wifi device is OvisLink Evo-W108USB

```
lsusb

Bus 001 Device 008: ID 0cf3:0002 Atheros Communications, Inc. AR5523 (no firmware)
```

I tried to install rpm from manufactured after convert to .deb file but unsuccesfully.

Answer (score 1):

*From [here](http://blog.radevic.com/2012/02/how-to-install-13855f01-netgear-wpn111.html)*

Install this package, depending on the version of ubuntu you may have:

```
12.04 (precise pangolin): https://launchpad.net/~medigeek/+archive/experimental/+files/ar5523-source_0%7Eslh.12%7Eppap1_all.deb

11.10 (oneiric ocelot): https://launchpad.net/~medigeek/+archive/experimental/+files/ar5523-source_0%7Eslh.12%7Eppao1_all.deb

11.04 (natty narwhal): https://launchpad.net/~medigeek/+archive/experimental/+files/ar5523-source_0%7Eslh.12%7Eppan1_all.deb
```

Execute the following commands, copy-paste them one by one:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get -f install
sudo apt-get upgrade
sudo apt-get install build-essential linux-headers-generic module-assistant
sudo m-a a-i ar5523-source
wget http://verein.lst.de/~hch/ar5523.tgz
tar xvf ar5523.tgz ar5523/uath-ar5523.bin --strip 1
sudo mv uath-ar5523.bin /lib/firmware
```

Comment: it worked for me on 12.04 64bit ubuntu server

Answer (score 0):

Please open a terminal and do:

```
sudo apt-get install linux-headers-generic build-essential subversion quilt deb-helper module-assistant
svn co svn://svn.berlios.de/fullstory/ar5523/trunk/ ar5523
wget http://verein.lst.de/~hch/ar5523.tgz
tar xf ar5523.tgz ar5523/uath-ar5523.bin --strip 1
cd ar5523
export QUILT_PATCHES="debian/patches"
quilt delete kcompat-3.5 && quilt delete kcompat-2.6.34
dpkg-buildpackage -us -uc
sudo su
dpkg -i ../ar5523-source*deb
m-a a-i ar5523
```

Now install the firmware:

```
mv ../uath-ar5523.bin /lib/firmware
modprobe ar5523
exit
```

Your wireless should now be working.